# Android: is there a way to buffer following mp3 file while playing current mp3?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I keep many mp3 files on a server to be able to receive them in my Android application. I am streaming mp3 files one after the other. My problem is that I want to already buffer the next mp3 file while playing the current mp3 file.

I tried it with already downloading the next mp3 file in cache while playing the first one. But the problem is that when the first mp3 file is done playing,  the second mp3 file may not be fully downloaded (which can easily happen on a 2g connection). The player will then initialize the part of the mp3 file which is downloaded and the player will play only that part of the downloaded files which is initialized (please correct me if I'm wrong). This causes corrupt files and it is not good performance at all.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For the file that you want to buffer, can you create a second MediaPlayer instance using [MediaPlayer create (Context context, Uri uri)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)), but not calling `.start()`, and then use [setNextMediaPlayer (MediaPlayer next)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setNextMediaPlayer(android.media.MediaPlayer)), to queue this second player to start playing when the first one is finished?